# Convert QByteArray to unsigned short: not as expected

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

I have a `QByteArray` like this:

```
QByteArray idx0;

// idx0 is then assigned 4 bytes,
// idx0 content is shown on debugger as:

// idx0 "\000\000\001\000"  QByteArray
//          '\0'    0       0x00    char
//          '\0'    0       0x00    char
//                  1       0x01    char
//          '\0'    0       0x00    char
```

I convert the `QbyteArray` to `unsigned short` like this:

```
unsigned short ushortIdx0;
if ( idx0.size() >= sizeof(ushortIdx0) ) {
    ushortIdx0 = *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned short *>( idx0.data() );
}
```

The Debugger shows `ushortIdx0` value as`0`:

```
// Debugger shows:
//
// ushortIdx0   0   unsigned short
```

---

**However**, when I convert the Little Endian value of `0x 00 00 01 00` to `UINT32 - Little Endian` by [this website](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/), I get:

```
UINT32 - Little Endian (DCBA):

Raw             UINT32
00 01 00 00     65536
```

---

**Why** the result of [that website](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/) is different from what I get by my code? I don't get it. I appreciate any help.

Comment: What makes you certain `sizeof(unsigned short)` is 4?

Comment: @G.M. Let me check ...

Comment: @user3405291 `*reinterpret_cast<const unsigned short *>( idx0.data() )` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @G.M. Wow! I double checked: `sizeof(unsigned short):  2`, therefore my assumption was totally wrong.

Comment: Besides that, you should never assume your machine has a certain endianness! Use [`qFromLittleEndian`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtendian.html#qFromLittleEndian) to get consistent results on any machine.

Comment: @Felix Right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment you can't always assume `unsigned short` is a certain size.  If you know that you need an unsigned integer with a certain number of bits then use the appropriate type from [`cstdint`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) -- `uint32_t` in this case.

With regard to endian issues, since you're using `Qt` why not use [`QDataStream`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html) to serialize/deserialize data in a platform agnostic manner.  Write an unsigned 32 bit integer using...

```
quint32 data = ...;
QByteArray ba;
QDataStream ds(&ba, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
ds << data;
```

And similarly to read the data back.